# SplayTreeSet contains duplicate values

Tags: dart, set, mobx, splay-tree

I have a `SplayTreeSet` of the objects `ChatRoomListModel`. I'd like to order my set based on the objects `DateTime createTime` value.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because there's duplicate items being added item.
I later down the line perform a `_latestMessages.add(newMessage)` and it's not actually calling the overloads and there's duplicates being added.

I tested by using `_latestMessage.contains(newMessageButSameChatRoomId)`, it returns false.

When I perform `_latestMessage.toSet()` every duplicate goes away.

How can I get `SplayTreeSet` to use my overloading equals?
Thanks!

```dart
  ObservableSet<ChatRoomListModel> _latestMessages = ObservableSet.splayTreeSetFrom(
    ObservableSet(),
    compare: (a, b) => b.compareTo(a),
  );
```

The `ChatRoomListModel` model has the following methods and overloads:

```dart
  int compareTo(ChatRoomListModel other){
    return messagesModel.createTime.compareTo(other.messagesModel.createTime);
  }

  ChatRoomListModel copyWith({
    String? firstName,
    String? otherUserId,
    MessagesModel? messagesModel,
  }) {
    return ChatRoomListModel(
      firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
      otherUserId: otherUserId ?? this.otherUserId,
      messagesModel: messagesModel ?? this.messagesModel,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ChatRoomListModel &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          messagesModel.chatRoomId == other.messagesModel.chatRoomId;

  @override
  int get hashCode => messagesModel.chatRoomId.hashCode;
```

Comment: It seems very strange that your `compareTo` and `operator ==` implementations have completely different notions of what constitutes element equality. `SplayTreeSet` considers elements to be equal only if `compareTo` returns 0.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah. Does the goal of having a list where each element has a unique `chatRoomId` and only the most recent `createTime` is kept possible?

Comment: To be clear: you want a data structure that keeps only the most recent message for a given `chatRoomId`?  If so, then you could maintain a `Map` of `chatRoomId`s to whatever the latest message is and replace items in the `Map` only if the replacement is newer than the existing value.

Comment: @jamesdlin Correct! But I then want the values ordered by createtime

Comment: I would use two data structures then.  You could encapsulate them together to ensure that they are kept in sync when entries are added or removed.

Comment: @jamesdlin If you can come with an efficient way to do so I'd be happy with that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have two completely different notions of what it means for two `ChatRoomListModel` objects to be "equal".  You provide both `compareTo` and `operator ==` implementations, but they consider different sets of properties, so `compareTo` can return 0 when `operator ==` returns false, which is confusing at best. `SplayTreeMap` considers *only* `compareTo`, not `operator ==`.  From [the `SplayTreeSet` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html):

> Elements of the set are compared using the `compare` function passed in the constructor, both for ordering and for equality. If the set contains only an object `a`, then s`et.contains(b)` will return `true` if and only if `compare(a, b) == 0`, and the value of `a == b` is not even checked.

I'm presuming what you call "duplicates" are elements that have equal `chatRoomId`s but that have different creation times, and creation times are the only things that your `SplayTreeSet` cares about.

If your goal is to maintain only the latest message per `chatRoomId`, you need to maintain a data structure that uses the `chatRoomId` (a `String`) as a key.  The natural collection for that would be a `Map<String, ChatRoomListModel>`. (Since the `ChatRoomListModel` knows its own `chatRoomId`, it also could just be a `HashSet` with explicit `equals` and `hashCode` callbacks.)

If you additionally want to keep messages in chronological order, you either will need to explicitly sort them afterward or maintain a separate data structure that keeps them in chronological order.  You could continue using a `SplayTreeSet` for that.  Basically before you add any entry to the `SplayTreeSet`, check the `Map` first to see if an existing entry for that `chatRoomId`.

I don't fully understand your data structures, but here's an example that you presumably can adapt:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class Message {
  Message(this.creationTime, {required this.chatRoomId, required this.text});

  final DateTime creationTime;
  final String chatRoomId;
  final String text;

  @override
  String toString() => '$creationTime: [$chatRoomId] $text';
}

class Messages {
  final _latestMessages = <String, Message>{};
  final _orderedMessages = SplayTreeSet<Message>((message1, message2) {
    var result = message1.creationTime.compareTo(message2.creationTime);
    if (result != 0) {
      return result;
    }
    result = message1.chatRoomId.compareTo(message2.chatRoomId);
    if (result != 0) {
      return result;
    }
    return message1.text.compareTo(message2.text);
  });

  void add(Message message) {
    var existingMessage = _latestMessages[message.chatRoomId];
    if (existingMessage != null &&
        message.creationTime.compareTo(existingMessage.creationTime) < 0) {
      // An existing message exists with a later creation date.  Ignore the
      // incoming message.
      return;
    }

    _latestMessages[message.chatRoomId] = message;
    _orderedMessages.remove(existingMessage);
    _orderedMessages.add(message);
  }

  void printAll() => _orderedMessages.forEach(print);
}

void main() {
  var messages = Messages();

  messages.add(Message(
    DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
    chatRoomId: 'foo',
    text: 'Hello foo!',
  ));

  messages.add(Message(
    DateTime(2023, 1, 2),
    chatRoomId: 'bar',
    text: 'Goodbye bar!',
  ));

  messages.add(Message(
    DateTime(2023, 1, 2),
    chatRoomId: 'foo',
    text: 'Goodbye foo!',
  ));

  messages.add(Message(
    DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
    chatRoomId: 'bar',
    text: 'Hello bar!',
  ));

  messages.printAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what `return message1.text.compareTo(message2.text);` does?

Comment: @DanMossa It does a string comparison. It's there to provide a strict, canonical ordering.  Without it, then two `Message`s with identical `creationTime` and `chatRoomId` values would be considered equal even if they had different values for `text`.